# Clarity regarding Aq Al-Walidayn

Tags: halal-haram, parents

As-Salamu alaikum brothers and sisters, I want to know if for example,
(1) your mother told you to put the milk on the fridge, and you don't do it because you're too tired, is this Aq Al-Walidayn? 
(2) and is shouting at a parent also Aq Al-Walidayn? 
(3) and is Aq Al-Walidayn a sin even if your parents forgive you?
(4) or if you disobey them forgetfully?

Barak Allahu feekum and Jazakum Allah khayran and remember, don't let this site distract you from your duties to Allah. May Allah guide us. And don't spend too much time in any answer or question just say what's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Parental wisdom is one of the great sins and moral vices. Deprivation of parents means that the child annoys the parents and annoys them with his language and behavior. [1] In the narrations, a sharp and angry look [4], loss of rights, [5] Examples of non-fulfillment of request, non-fulfillment of orders, disrespect [6] are considered.

In other words, the expulsion of parents is the same as disobedience to parents, disregarding their orders and not doing good to them. Deprivation of parents is a great sin. Whoever reaches the stage of divorcing his parents will not be forgiven by God Almighty.
Things that cause parents to be separated: anger, heartbreak, annoyance, raising their voices, cursing, looking angry, disobeying their parents' orders, and telling them off are examples of being separated from their parents. (2)

"To compensate for the separation of the parents, if they are alive:

- You must prove to your parents that you no longer intend to repeat such an action.
- Because your parents are upset because of this cruelty, it is better to show more respect, politeness and obedience to them than before. Which softens your parents' heart. Finally, humbly and with supplication and supplication from God Almighty and the Imams (AS) ask your parents to forgive you. Rest assured that the merciful God created the heart of the parents out of His kindness. It is not possible for a child to apologize to them and they will not forgive him.
  But if they are not alive,
- Obligations from those who have died while living, such as prayer, fasting, Hajj and their debts.
- Do what they have bequeathed.
- They should not be forgotten for the rest of their lives. We must ask for their forgiveness and mercy. He gave alms on their behalf. Perform the recommended deeds with their intentions. (3)

> 1- Naraghi, Ascension of Happiness, 1378, p. 532 . 4 Klini, Al-Kafi,
> 1407 AH, vol. 2, p. 349.
> 5. Tamimi Amadi, Gharr al-Hakam, 1410 AH, p. 671.
> 6. Nouri, Mustadrak al-Wasa'il, 1408 AH, vol. 15, p. 194.

Answer (score -1):

(1) It doesn't matter you are tired.

(2) Shouting is not best option maybe raise voice but if you mad go out for a walk or spend time away then discuss with them in good manner.

(3) And is Aq Al-Walidayn a sin even if your parents forgive you? (Still a sin)

(4) Or if you disobey them forgetfully? (You don't mean it so no)